# How do Crab-N-Go food multipliers stack?

Tags: splatoon-3

If I have a x2 cash multiplier active from a Commercial Crab Trap Sandwich and someone on my team has a 'teamwide x2 multiplier' from a Mega Mountain a la Marigold, how do they stack?

Do they multiply together for a x4? or add to each other giving a x3? Or does the game just take whatever multiplier is highest and applies that one only?